# Cauchy Principal Value Problem: Gaussian and exponential over a quadratic

Tags: improper-integrals

I need help with the following integral:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x^2}e^{iax}}{1-x^2}dx$$

Where $a$ is real.

Obviously the integral doesn't converge due to the singularities at $|x|=1$ but I am interested in the principal value of this integral. However I am confused about whether to take my contour above or below each of the singularities.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: For $a=0$ we have $I=\dfrac\pi e\text{erfi}(1)$. Otherwise, even its principal value seems to diverge.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can find this PV in closed form. But you can set the odd part to 0 and use symmetry to reduce it to 
$$
2 PV \int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{-x^2}\cos ax}{1-x^2} dx
$$
For a real PV, you would omit an interval of length $\epsilon$ on either side of the singularity.
$$
I = 2 \left ( \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0 } \int_{0}^{1-\epsilon}\dfrac{e^{-x^2}\cos ax}{1-x^2} dx + \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0 } \int_{1+\epsilon}^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{-x^2}\cos ax}{1-x^2} dx \right )
$$

In the complex plane, you would join the ends of the excised intervals by a semi-circle of radius $\epsilon$ above the x-axis to get a contour that excluded the singularities.

Don't know if that helps.